# Iterate Over X Lines in Variable (Bash)

Tags: bash, loops, curl, printing, lines

I'm trying to write a simple script to print the first 5 lines of a webpage's source code, and then the request time it took for the page to load. Currently, I've been trying the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Enter a website, get data

output=$(curl $1 -s -w "%{time_connect}\n" | (head -n5; tail -n1))
echo "$output"
```

However, on some pages, the "tail" doesn't actually print, which should be the time to request, and I'm not sure why.

I've found that I can also use a while loop to iterate through lines and print the whole thing, but is there a way for me to just echo the first few lines of a variable and then the last line of that same variable, so I can precede the request time with a heading (ex: *Request time: 0.489)*?

I'd like to be able to format it as:

```
echo "HTML: $output\n" 
echo "Request Time: $requestTime"
```

Thank you! Sorry if this seems very simple, I am really new to this language :). The main problem for me is getting this data all from the same request- doing two separate curl requests would be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` may read more than 5 lines of input in order to identify what it needs to output. This means the lines you intended to pass to `tail` may have already been consumed. It's safer to use a single process (`awk`, in this case) to handle all the output.

```
output=$(curl "$1" -s -w "%{time_connect}\n" | awk 'NR<=5 {print} END {print})
```

Answer (score 0):

The carriage returns threw me.  Try this:

```
echo "HTML: "
retn=$'\r'

i=0
while read item
do
    item="${item/$retn/}"    # Strip out the carriage-return

    if (( i < 5 )); then     # Only display the first 5 lines
        echo "$item"
    fi

    (( i++ ))
    requestTime="$item"    # Grab the last line

done < <(curl $1 -s -w "%{time_connect}\n")

requestTime="${requestTime##*\>}"    # Sanitise the last line

echo "Request Time: $requestTime"
```